# Plugin WordPress JSON API - How get posts for category with offset?

Tags: json, wordpress, api, post, offset

for example in category "news" of my blog there are 50 posts.
For get last 10 posts I do:
http://mywordpress.com/?json=get_category_posts&slug=news&count=10&status=publish
And it work correctly.
Now I want to get my posts from 11 to 20 skipping last 10 posts, etc.
How can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The post count defaults to whatever you set in the wordpress backend (settings -> reading). You can achieve pagination by just adding the page parameter. So if you want the posts 11-20 you just call

```
http://mywordpress.com/?json=get_category_posts&slug=news&count=10&status=publish&page=2
```

You find more information here: [JSON API Plugin Page, Other Notes](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#2.1.-Core-controller-methods)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use get_category_posts with offset.

You have to construct the query from the basic get_posts which has a lot of parameters, see here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

and here (read Method: get_posts):

http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

I think you should use something like:

> blablabla.xxx/?json=get_posts&count=10&status=published&cat='id of the category news'&offset='int offset'

Be aware that use offset 'breaks' pagination